# specific post is not excluded from the loop

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, exclude

I have registered a CPT and created  **archive-myCPT.php**, here I want to exclude a specific post from the main loop.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => 'cpt',
   'orderby' => 'date', 
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'posts__not_in' => array( 118 ),
   'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
        if( $query->have_posts() ){ 
            // normal blog layout
                $x = 1;
                while ( $query->have_posts() ){
                    $query->the_post(); 
                    if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent ) {
                    get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');
                }
  ........................
```

All the other arguments are working as expected but the `'posts__not_in' => array( 118 ),` is not working, I still see it.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

This more relevant code which I'm using for the loop:

```
<?php 

        if( have_posts() ){ 
            // normal blog layout
                $x = 1;
                while ( have_posts() ){
                    the_post(); 
                    if ($post->ID != 118) {
                    get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');
                }


                    // advertising between posts
                    if($ad_posts_mode != 'none'){
                        // take into account ad frequency
                        if (($x % $ad_posts_frequency) == 0){

                            switch ($ad_posts_mode) {
                                case 'image':
                                    echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts"><a target="_blank" href="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image_link').'"><img src="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image').'"></a></div>';
                                break;
                                case 'html':
                                    echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts">'.apply_filters('shortcode_filter',do_shortcode(of_get_option('ad_posts_code'))).'</div>';
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code examples are inconsistent with each other. Please narrow it down to what you actually have right now and all of it together - how are you modifying loop and how do you output results.

Comment: Is 118 a sticky post, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just off by one letter it seems.

```
post__not_in => array(118)
```

[Post & Page Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

You can also try adding an if statement, such as:

```
if($post->ID != 118) :
```

... run rest of code

Though not optimal, without seeing the rest of your template I can't be certain.

Additional Edit:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'       => 'cpt',
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1
));
if($loop->have_posts()) :while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    if($post->ID != 118) :
?>
The Title is: <?php the_title(); ?>. The ID is: <?php $post->ID; ?>
<?php endif; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Using this simple example on a test CPT I created, and creating a few test posts (plus using a random ID from one of them), the post did not display. If it still displays for you, it is either not the correct $post->ID, or you're missing something from your examples.

Comment: Tried it, but still not excluded...

Comment: Either way, that is the correct parameter, not what you have. I have added an additional comment to the original solution.

Comment: I've updated my question with more relevant code which I'm using for the loop and I've added also `if($post->ID != 118)` still not excluded.

Comment: I am going to modify your first initial bit of code, and hopefully you can run it for me. It'll be added onto my previous answer.